# Pandas - How to substract one cell from another cell based on other columns values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, difference

[image]

I need to calculate a difference score between 2 cells in the columns 'Negative Emotions - Mean', with the same values in the columns 'participant_id' and 'session'. the difference score is block=neg minus block=neu
My expected output is presented in the column 'difference_score'

How can I do it pandas, without building a dictionary?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Would you mind providing us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can we use in order to work with a part of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to leverage pandas' [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) functions.

Groupby groups your DataFrame based on the specified columns, then apply runs whatever function you pass through over the GroupBy object.

So, first, let's formulate the logic you'd like to do, first, you want to groupby the participant_id and the session, then you'd like to get the value for the neg, and the value for the neu, and then place this difference into a new column named difference_score.

```
# This function will get the difference from the grouped rows.
def get_score_difference(rows: pd.DataFrame):
    # Get neg value in a try catch block, ensuring neg is defaulted to 0 if not in df
    try:
        neg = rows.loc[rows['block'] == 'neg']['Negative Emotion - Mean'][0]
    except Exception as e:
        neg = 0

    # Get neu value in the same fashion as neg
    try:
        neu = rows.loc[rows['block'] == 'neu']['Negative Emotion - Mean'][0]
    except Exception as e:
        neu = 0

    # Add new column with neg - neu
    rows['difference_score'] = neg - neu

    # Return new rows
    return rows

# Apply the function to the dataframe
df.groupby(['participant_id', 'session']).apply(get_score_difference)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
I think it didn't work because missing values - for example, for subject number 12 I have only block = 'neg' in the first session (session =1)

here is the error I got:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works great :)
 [I had to add very minor addition, {maybe  because the interpreter in Collab?} of: 
df = df.groupby(['participant_id', 'session']).apply(get_score_difference)]

Answer (score 1):

Over simple way would be to set the ID columns as index and using a mask:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['participant_id', 'session'])

mask = df2['block'].eq('neg')

df2['difference_score'] = df2.loc[mask, 'Negative Emotions - Mean']-df2.loc[~mask, 'Negative Emotions - Mean']

df2.reset_index()
```

*No output provided as the data was an image.*